# Размещение контента на странице wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, довольно долго гуглил, прежде чем спросить, в общем суть вопроса: на Wordpress оформлено что то типа каталога продукции, один продукт - это запись, при открытии этой записи нужно чтобы контент располагался согласно верстке как на скрине, но ведь в цикле есть только , в записи я указал миниатюру, а в контент написал текст и картинки, как теперь все это дело можно расположить согласно верстке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="item_description">

                            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
                            <div class="post-cat-three">
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                <div class="post">
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                    <div class="entry">
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                                    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Woocommerce поставь

Comment: Я изначально не стал плагинами баловаться, так что все сделано без них.

Comment: Код добавьте в тело вопроса

Comment: @eugene_v готово

Comment: Цикл я так понимаю Вы брали с этого примера https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress т.к. используете проверку category id

Comment: @eugene_v да, брал оттуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если собственные плагины тоже нельзя написать, то только в ручную каждую страницу верстать.

Если с плагинами, то вам подойдет:

[acf](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) - кастомные поля для записей. С помощью него вы создадите ваш правый блок с характеристиками, и очень просто будет верстать.

Для слайдера в этом случае может подойти пример отсюда: [ссылка](https://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/slider-for-post-images.html)

Верстаете все один раз, и существенно облегчаете себе работу по добавлению контента.

Comment: В общем весь ACF решил все мои проблемы))) Задал поля для текста и поля для картинок, после чего в теле цикла вывел в нужные мне ссылки для карусели, и все заработало!)

Answer (score 0):

Ничего хорошего тут не скажешь, судя по коду Вы выводите все в теле контента, соответственно вам нужно будет каждый пост подгонять под свой формат, когда-то вам это надоест и Вы все переделаете. На данный момент вам нужно в контенте прописывать блоки DIV с классами и стилями подгонять. Когда сделаете 1 пост, потом будете переносить тело в другой и менять только содержимое, но это такой "костыль"...

Почему Вы главное изображение не вывели миниатюрой?

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
the_content();
```

Comment: Главное изображение должно меняться при нажатии на список картинок вниз, скрипт есть, но вот как настроить все....попробую вариант ответа ниже для подключения слайдера.

Comment: Тогда, да. Вам нужно будет использовать какой-то из скриптов карусели или слайдера. В вопросе этого не указано